# success function does not work second time in dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js. It's working fine for first time but when I tried to upload image second time then success function does not get exicuted.
I am using following code, problem in here is that when i click a button then a popup opens and i select image and the functionality in the success function works fine. When I click submit button then popup disappears. If I follow the same process again then success function does not get exicuted.

```
                var thumbnailwidth = 100;
                var thumbnailheight = 100;

                var mydropzone = null;
                function initDropZone(){
                    var preview_template  = $('#preview-template').html();

                    mydropzone = $("#gpZUpload").dropzone({
                        url: "<?php echo CHILD_DIR;?>/buddypress/activity/upload.php",
                        thumbnailHeight:10000,
                        thumbnailWidth:10000,
                        maxFiles:1,
                        // previewTemplate: preview_template,
                        previewsContainer: "#preview",  
                        success: function (file, response) {
                            var obj1 = $.parseJSON(response);
                            var imgName = obj1.image_url;
                            window.thumbnailwidth = obj1.width;
                            window.thumbnailheight = obj1.height;
                            var image_location=imgName
                            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                            input.setAttribute("name", "image_url");
                            input.setAttribute("value", imgName);
                            file.previewTemplate.appendChild(input);
                            //$('.crop-button').trigger('click');
                            initJCrop();
                        },
                        error: function (file, response) {
                            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                        } 
                    });
                }


                mydropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                    alert('hello');
                });

            function initJCrop(){
                $('#preview img[data-dz-thumbnail]').Jcrop({            
                    trueSize: [window.thumbnailwidth,window.thumbnailheight],
                    onChange:showCoords,
                    onSelect:showCoords,
                    bgOpacity:.4,
                    setSelect:[210, 245, 800, 600 ],
                    aspectRatio:16/9
                });
            }

            function showCoords(c){
                $('.x1_cords').val(c.x);
                $('.y1_cords').val(c.y);
                $('.x2_cords').val(c.x2);
                $('.y2_cords').val(c.y2);
                $('.new_width').val(c.w);
                $('.new_height').val(c.h);
            };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I have found that if we set  maxFiles:n where 'n' is a number then success function gets called only n times in my case 1 time. So I omitted it, and it started running fine.